Use AWS Cognito custom attribute in React Amplify query filter
I am new to React so I apologise up front! I am developing a "simple" app in AWS Amplify with a DynamoDb database and Cognito Authentication.
My requirement is that I read a custom user attribute (custom:customer_id) from cognito and use that value as a filter to both queries (for CustomerSummary and CustomerRecommendations).
The behaviour I am seeing is that if I hard code setCompanyId("1234567890"); my application works fine (albeit with a hardcoded value) but if I call my getUserAttributes() function I see the default "999999999" briefly before it changes to undefined
Please help before I throw my laptop out of the window.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import type { Schema } from "../amplify/data/resource";
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/data";
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import { fetchUserAttributes } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import AccountSummary from "./AccountSummary";
import CustomerRecommendations from "./CustomerRecommendations";
const client = generateClient<Schema>();

const getUserAttributes = async () => {
    const userAttributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
    return String(userAttributes['custom:customer_id']);
};

function App() {
  const [summaries, setSummaries] = useState<Array<Schema["CustomerSummary"]["type"]>>([]);
  const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState<Array<Schema["CustomerRecommendation"]["type"]>>([]);
  const [companyId, setCompanyId] = useState<String>("999999999");
 
  // HOW SHOULD THIS LINE BE IMPLEMENTED?
  useEffect(() => {
    // WITH THIS LINE I SEE "999999999" BRIEFLY AND THEN IT GOES UNDEFINED
    // getUserAttributes().then((customerId) => setCompanyId(customerId) );
    // WITH THIS LINE MY APPLICATION WORKS FINE
    setCompanyId("1234567890");
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    client.models.CustomerSummary.observeQuery({filter: {
      customer_id: {        
        eq: companyId?.toString()
      }
    }}).subscribe({
      next: (data) => setSummaries([...data.items]),
    });
  }, [companyId]);
  useEffect(() => {
    client.models.CustomerRecommendation.observeQuery({filter: {
      customer_id: {
        eq: companyId?.toString()
      }
    }}).subscribe({
      next: (data) => setRecommendations([...data.items]),
    });
  }, [companyId]);
...

I have tried moving my function in and out of my component but the behaviour is the same. I am expecting the correct value of "1234567890" to be read when the page loads and then the query filters use that value

Have you tried adding a dependency to your first useEffect? for example
useEffect(() => {
setCompanyId("1234567890");
},[]);
